# Count unique values in a column depending on unique values in a second column

Tags: google-sheets

I am having a table that lists salespersons, to which company they outreach, and which outreach channel (e.g. email, call etc.) they are using. I am interested in calculating how many times a unique salesperson reached out by the respective channel but to only count unique companies. I.e. if a salesperson called the same company 2 or more times I only want to count it once. This is part of the table:

[image]

Now if I try to calculate it in the yellow cell, the following formula:

=(COUNTIFS(B:B,A1,D:D,"Call"))

returns three because I couldn't find a way how I bring column B (Company) into the picture. Does anyone know how I can achieve the desired result of counting only 2 as Marc called three times but two times into the same company (A)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to go about this. Here is one:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B&C:C,B:B=A1,D:D="Call"))))`

Another type of summary may interest you was well. Suppose that the data shown in your post is in a sheet called Sheet1. Create a new sheet and place this formula in A1 of that new sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY({Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!C:C&": "&Sheet1!D:D},"Select Col2, COUNT(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1")))`

This will produce an easy-to-read total unique count for every person for every communication means for every company.

Comment: Hey Erik, 
Many thanks. I used your first solution as it looked more simple. Indeed the summary table where I show the result of a calculation is on another sheet ("Calls_Bencharking") than the main data. Your first version seems to function most of the times. 

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Calls_Benchmarking!A:A&Calls_Benchmarking!B:B,Calls_Benchmarking!A:A=A17,Calls_Benchmarking!C:C="Call")))

But it looks like it gives back a "1" where there should be no hits i.e. a "0". Can I build in a Not Null statement in the first version of your answer? How?

Regards, 
Marc

Comment: See the update to my first formula, Marc. The 1 is there if there are no unique matching values, because `COUNTA` counts an error as "something." So wrapping the inner part of the formula in `IFERROR(   )` will return null if there are no unique matches, and `COUNTA` will return 0.

Comment: Hey Erik, thanks it worked great! Many thanks for your help here!!!

Comment: You're welcome, Marc. Please take a moment to mark the answer post as "Best Answer." This allows the contributor community here to see at a glance which issues have been fully resolved; and it helps future site visitors more easily find the most relevant answers.